# Cómo relacionar columnas en Lavarel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Quisiera saber cómo puedo unir dos tablas en laravel para poder mostrar el contenido de otra tabla.
Tengo la tabla usuarios donde agrego los ID de otra tabla que sirve como catálogo.[image: Ejemplo]

Quisiera poder relacionar las tablas para mostrar su descripción en vez del ID por ejemplo de la subdirección.

**Controlador:**

```
public function index() 
{
    //$users=User::all();
    $departamentos=CatDepartamento::all();
    $subdirecciones=CatSubdireccion::where('descripcion','<>','Dirección')->get();
    $puestos=CatPuesto::where([
                ['id_puesto', '<>', 1],
                ['id_puesto', '<>', 3]
            ])->get();
    $estatus=CatEstatus::all();
   // $users=User::where('id_puesto','>',1)->get();
    $users=User::where('id_puesto','>',1)->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.users.index')->with(compact('users','departamentos','subdirecciones','puestos','estatus')); 
}
```

**Vista**

```
                            <tbody class="text-center">
                                @foreach($users as $user)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $user->no_empleado }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->name }} {{ $user->ap_paterno }} {{ $user->ap_materno }}</td>  
                                    <td>{{ $user->no_tarjeta }}</td>    
                                    <td>{{ $user->id_subdireccion }}</td>                                    
                                    <td>{{ $user->id_departamento }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->id_puesto }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->id_estatus }}</td>
                                    <td><a href="/usuario/{{ $user->id }}"class="btn btn-sm btn-info" title="editar">Ver más <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>     <a href="/usuario/{{ $user->id }}"class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" title="editar">Editar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>     <a href="/usuario/{{ $user->id }}/eliminar" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" title="eliminar">Eliminar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar por favor, gracias.Uso laravel 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy fácil, te dejo el enlace de la documentación y te pongo un ejemplo.
Si tu relación es 1-1 tienes que usar hasOne con los parametros (clase, clave primaria en el modelo de la relación, clave foranea en el modelo actual)

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(CatSubdireccion::class, 'id','id_subdireccion');
    }
}
```

Tambien deberias modificar las consultas para que añada las relaciones usando with:

```
$usuarios = Users::with(['categoria'])->get();
```

Ahora en tu blade podrias hacer esto

```
<td>{{ $user->categoria->nombre}}</td>
```

[DOCUMENTACION PARA 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)